# Working with ISO-8859-1 Character Set in Python with Mechanize

Tags: python, string, utf-8, mechanize, iso-8859-1

I am using python and mechanize to scrape a website that uses the ISO-8859-1 character set. Among other things, within the html apparently special apostrophes (’ as opposed to ') display as `&#146;`. How do I encode/decode the html so that these characters are stored in  and display correctly in a normal python string or encoded utf-8 and display a unicode string correctly? Keep in mind that what mechanize gives me is html in `<type 'str'>`. My basic scrapping code is below, unfortunately the site is not public and I cannot find a public site that uses the character set to create a reproducible example.

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
mech = mechanize.OpenerFactory().build_opener(mechanize.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
request = mechanize.Request(url)
response = mech.open(request)
html = response.read()
```